# Create Directory and Change Permissions in Cookiecutter Django with selenium/standalone-chrome-debug

Tags: docker, selenium, cookiecutter-django

I need some help incorporating a solution to a problem I have encountered from someone with a bit more Docker experience than me!

I am using [Cookiecutter-Django](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/docs/index.rst) with Docker to host my Django app. I have included Selenium using [selenium-standalone-debug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium).

I am unable to download files in Selenium due to my selenium user not having root access, and the mounted directory that I am downloading to being created by a root user, and therefore requiring root privileges.

I have found the recommended solution is below; but I don't know where to include the 2 lines of code into my Django-Cookiecutter project. Can someone explain where these lines are supposed to go?
[image: Solution to my problem]

Many Thanks for any help anyone can offer!